# Android Studio 3.0.1 AVD Bug - Old Android not Downloadable

Tags: android, android-studio, device

I need create a Virtual Device with Android 5 but Download button is not available in Android Studio for Any Device:

[image]

and

[image]

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm which components for API level 21/22 have you installed?
Below is the snapshot of my components that I have installed.

Once you install them you will see options for creating AVD for API level 21/22

Also make sure you click on "show package details" on bottom right corner of sdk manager

[image: SDK Manager snapshot for API level 21]